# win phone scrolling ListBox not working

Tags: listbox, scroll, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

in win phone when having two Grids one after another and each has it's own listBox the scrolling is not working.
Any ideas ?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
    Background="Transparent">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <ListBox x:Name="lstData1"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productCollection}, Path=DataCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        .................
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="lstData2"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productCollection}, Path=DataCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                ..................
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Thank you
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Height must be specified for the scroll to work